# Parse Dashboard Settings

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I'm using Parse Server Dashboard on Heroku with my iOS app and I would like to configure Push Notifications. I know I can configure this in App Settings, but in the dashboard I can only see Core and Push. On screenshots online I see there's another tab but in my dashboard this doesn't appear.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you change app settings like push is different now that we have to use Parse Server. Before, it was built into their Dashboard interface, but now you have to manually enter that information in your **index.js** file. Referring to [this](http://rogerstringer.com/2016/02/11/parse-server-push/) article, it should look like this:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: 'MYAPPID',
    clientKey: 'myclientKey',  
    masterKey: 'myMasterKey',
    push: {
        android: {
            senderId: '', // The Sender ID of GCM
            apiKey: '' // The Server API Key of GCM
        },
        ios: {
            pdx: 'certs/mycert.p12', // the path and filename to the .p12 file you exported earlier. 
            bundleId: '', // The bundle identifier associated with your app
            production: true
        }
    }
});
```

You'll have to grab the certificate information from each of the providers yourself, and simply include the .p12 certificate file somewhere near your index.js and you're golden.

Comment: Very helpful! However, the article mentions some terminal commands, but how do I get there? Should I be looking for the index.js file in my MongoDB Database on Heroku? Thanks man!

Comment: If you want to change anything in your Parse Server stuff hosted on Heroku, you have to first clone whatever is Heroku to your own computer, make the changes, then push your changes back to Heroku. This is all using git. I'm sure you can find some useful tutorials online. You can go to your Heroku app, go to **Deploy** then follow their instructions to clone to your machine. Then when you've made the appropriate changes, in terminal use "git push heroku master"